# Jenkins is complaining about syntax on a line I didn't change

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I had a curl call in one of the pipeline steps which was working just fine:

```
stage("deploy") {
        when {
                        environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_TO", value: "staging"
                }
            steps {
                // copy files from dev to  server
                sh """rsync...

                #....
                    /bin/cp .....


                rm -Rf /tmp/${env.SITEID}docs/
                # clear the  caches
               curl -sS -X POST \"http://www.xxxxxxxx.net/myscript.php?api_key=sdfsdfsdfe&site_id=088\""""
```

The problem started when I added an if conditional to that curl call in case that curl call failed:

```
stage("deploy") {
        when {
                        environment ignoreCase: true, name: "DEPLOY_TO", value: "staging"
                }
            steps {
                // copy files from dev to  server
                sh """rsync...

                #....
                    /bin/cp .....


                rm -Rf /tmp/${env.SITEID}docs/
                # clear the  caches
                if [[ $( curl -sS -X POST \"http://www.xxxxxxxx.net/myscript.php?api_key=sdfsdfsdfe&site_id=088\" | jq -r .debug_info.id_info) != \" cache cleared successfuly\" ]]; then exit 255; fi"""
```

The error is now pointing to the line of code `rm -Rf /tmp/${env.SITEID}docs/` but the confusion is that I didn't even changed that line of code!

The error message I get is the following:

```
ERROR: WorkflowScript: 119: illegal string body character after dollar sign;
   solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 119, column 41.
         rm -Rf /tmp/${env.SITEID}docs/
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is still in the line you modified:

```
if [[ $( curl -sS -X POST \"http://www.xxxxxxxx.net/myscript.php?api_key=sdfsdfsdfe&site_id=088\" | jq -r .debug_info.id_info) != \" cache cleared successfuly\" ]]; then exit 255; fi
```

Although the output line and column are incorrect, the body of the message is accurate. Note the message:

> illegal string body character after dollar sign;
>   solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}"

This is because of the part with `$( curl` where that dollar sign is being interpreted as denoting a Groovy and/or Jenkins variable interpolated within a string. The two suggestions given in the error are based upon whether you meant that or not. If you meant that, then you need to bracket it like:

```
${( curl...}
```

but, since you did not mean that and instead wanted a shell variable interpolation inside the string, you need the former suggestion and escape the `$`.

Your resulting line appears like:

```
if [[ \$( curl -sS -X POST \"http://www.xxxxxxxx.net/myscript.php?api_key=sdfsdfsdfe&site_id=088\" | jq -r .debug_info.id_info) != \" cache cleared successfuly\" ]]; then exit 255; fi
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your comment. It was very well explained. You are right, I should've read the error message in more detail. Thank you again.